Lan Link would autonegotiate to 10Mbitps and wont connect at 1Gbitps Linkspeed any more
Running win 11 latest version on a desktop pc
pc/cable/router used to connect at 1000 Mbitps Full duplex and now barely can hold a connection at 100 Mbitps and defaults to 10 Mbitps
purchased a LAN Pcie card and achieved same result
tested the same cable and router on a laptop and managed to hold 1Gbitps connection.
pretty 6 yo PC (used heavily), my only conclusion was that the motherboard/cpu is dying

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

are both the device and the router/switch set to auto-negotiate?

10/100Mb only requires half of the cable pairs to work (or even sometimes), so this is usually due to a bad cable or the physical ethernet ports at either end. Try a different port on the router first if possible, then try with a new cable

@Cpt.Whale that was also my assumption. so i tried a new port on both ends.
still the same results. but on laptop works flawlessly, can it be software issue ?

@FrankThomas tried both autonegotiate and manual link speed. autonegotiate takes some time but in the end connects at 10 MB , but manually setting to 100 MB sometimes works too

What happens if you manually set it to 1Gbps in Device Manager > Network Adapters > your network card properties > advanced > "speed& duplex"? Were you able to try a new cable with the desktop? It can easily be that the cable's broken, but only causes issues in certain positions for example. There's not much else to check other than if you have some interference from some massive power supply/magnet/heater or something

@Cpt.Whale , two scenarios: it would either not change to 1 Gbps , or if it would (need to reset pc) then there would be no connection/ no lan cable detection
